# Minimal point of a intersection of $n$ convex sets is always the minimal point of the intersection of two convex sets?

Tags: convex-optimization

I have the intuition that the minimal point (in the sense of having the lowest value in one of the Euclidean space dimensions)  of a intersection of $n$ convex sets is always the minimal point of the intersection of two convex sets in the family. Has this been proven before?

Answer (score 3):

In $d$ dimensions, you need at least $d$ convex sets, not two.  For example, in a suitably rotated polytope in $d$ dimensions, the minimal point will be a vertex, which is defined by the intersection of $d$ planes.

Comment: Many thanks Geoffrey, my problem is in two dimensions. Is there a known result that states that in $d$ dimensions you need at least $d$ convex sets to define a minimal point?